# Accessing a pointer stored in a base class

Tags: c++, pointers, base-class

I have a class called StateMachine, which controls all possible Entity States.

I then have a class called State which is a base class for unique Entity classes, e.g Attack State, Flee State.

When a new unique State is created (within the StateMachine), it passes in a StateMachine pointer, which will then be stored in the State base class, so that each unique State created can access its State Machine.

When I attempt to access the pointers members (using -> operator) it simple doesn't come up with any public methods, and I don't know why.

If anyone has any clue it would be greatly appreciated.

StateMachine.h

```
using STATE_PTR = std::shared_ptr<State>;

// Class to implement a finite state machine using the state desing pattern

    class StateMachine
    {
    public:
    StateMachine();
    ~StateMachine();

    void OnEnter(STATE_NAME sn);
    void OnExit();
    void OnEvent(STATE_SYMBOL & ss);
    void OnTick(float st);
    void ChangeState(STATE_NAME const & sn);
    void RegisterState(ENTITY_CLASS const & ec);

    typedef std::map<STATE_NAME, STATE_PTR>     STATE_REGISTRY;

private:
    STATE_REGISTRY  state_registry;
    STATE_NAME      current_state;
};
```

StateMachine.cpp

```
using namespace::std;


StateMachine::StateMachine()
    : state_registry()
{
    current_state = STATE_NAME::UNKNOWN;
}

StateMachine::~StateMachine()
{
    state_registry.clear();
}

void StateMachine::OnEnter(STATE_NAME sn)
{
    current_state = sn;

    if (state_registry[current_state] != nullptr)
    {
        state_registry[current_state]->OnEnter();
    }
}

void StateMachine::OnExit()
{
    if (state_registry[current_state] != nullptr)
    {
        state_registry[current_state]->OnExit();
    }
}

void StateMachine::OnTick(float st)
{

}

void StateMachine::OnEvent(STATE_SYMBOL & ss)
{
    state_registry[current_state]->OnEvent(ss);
}

void StateMachine::RegisterState(ENTITY_CLASS const & ec)
{
    switch (ec)
    {
    case ENTITY_CLASS::PLAYER_TANK :
        state_registry.insert(std::make_pair(STATE_NAME::STATE_1, std::make_shared<PlayerTankState1>(this)));
        state_registry.insert(std::make_pair(STATE_NAME::STATE_2, std::make_shared<PlayerTankState2>(this)));
        break;
    case ENTITY_CLASS::ENEMY_TANK :
        state_registry.insert(std::make_pair(STATE_NAME::STATE_3, std::make_shared<EnemyTankState1>(this)));
        state_registry.insert(std::make_pair(STATE_NAME::STATE_4, std::make_shared<EnemyTankState2>(this)));
        state_registry.insert(std::make_pair(STATE_NAME::STATE_5, std::make_shared<EnemyTankState3>(this)));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void StateMachine::ChangeState(STATE_NAME const & sn)
{
    state_registry[current_state]->OnExit();
    current_state = sn;
    state_registry[current_state]->OnEnter();
}
```

State.h

```
class StateMachine;         // Forward decloration of the StateMachine class

// Base class for all states of the game system
class State
{
protected:
    State(StateMachine * p)
        : mp_Owner(p)
    {}

public:
    virtual ~State() {}

    virtual void OnEnter() = 0;
    virtual void OnExit() = 0;
    virtual void OnTick(float) = 0;
    virtual void OnEvent(STATE_SYMBOL) = 0;

    StateMachine * mp_Owner;
};
```

EnemyTankState.cpp (Unique State)

```
    EnemyTankState1::EnemyTankState1(StateMachine * p)
    : State(p)
{
}

EnemyTankState1::~EnemyTankState1()
{
}

void EnemyTankState1::OnEnter()
{
    cout << "Hi From Enemy Tank: Partolling State" << endl;
}

void EnemyTankState1::OnExit()
{
    cout << "Bye From Enemy Enemy Tank: Partolling State" << endl;
}

void EnemyTankState1::OnTick(float dt)
{

}

void EnemyTankState1::OnEvent(STATE_SYMBOL ss)
{

    switch (ss)
    {
    // Takes Enemy Tank to Attacking State
    case STATE_SYMBOL::SYMBOL_2 :
        mp_Owner->
        break;
    }
}
```

Within the code sample above, the line `mp_Owner->` is what is giving me grief, as it is not opening up a list of public methods as you would expect when using a class pointer.

Any help would be much appreciated. Sorry for the long chunks of code, I couldn't think of any other way of getting my problem across.

Comment: I don't have enough information about `EnemyTankState1` to provide a useful response. Could be a mistake in the intelisense or whatever your IDE calls the suggestion engine. Could be just about anything. Type the member you want in, compile it, and see if the compiler gives you any useful information.

Comment: So I typed in the `StateMachine` function I wish to execute, `mp_Owner->ChangeState(STATE_NAME::STATE_4);` and the red line error underneath `mp_Owner` reads: `pointer to imcomplete class type is not allowed`.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. You'll get a circular dependency is you include StateMachine.h in State.h, but you should be able to include it in EnemyTankState.cpp. The `class StateMachine;` forward declaration isn't enough to be able to do more than hold a reference to `StateMachine`.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a whirl and get back to you on how it went. Thanks for your help.